# Is every monotone Lagrangian Hamiltonian isotopic to minimal Lagrangian?

Tags: sg.symplectic-geometry, kahler-manifolds, complex-manifolds, lagrangian-submanifolds

Assume we have a closed Lagrangian submanifold $L$ in Kaehler-Einstein manifold of positive scalar curvature (for instance, complex projective space). Dazord has proved that 1-form $\alpha=\omega(\bullet, H)$ is closed ($H$ is the mean curvature vector field) thus it gives us a class in $H^1(L, \mathbb{R})$. It is well-known that for monotone submanifolds $[\alpha]=0$ and monotonocity condition is preserved under Hamiltonian isotopy (for instance, Goldstein-Cieliebak 2003).

My question is: can we always move $L$ by Hamiltonian isotopy to a minimal Lagrangian, i.e. one with $H=0$?

Some motivation is following. Biran and Cornea have constructed famous examples of monotone Lagrangian tori in $\mathbb{C}P^2$ with trivial Floer cohomology. I am interested in minimal Lagrangian tori with trivial Floer cohomology but it is hard for me to prove or disprove minimality of those examples.